# Are there any problems when using pure C (not class-wrapped) functions in C++ application?

Tags: c++, c, interop

I am planning to use pure C MPI library in C++ application, I don't want to add unnecessary bloat by running eg. Boost MPI layer that wraps all stuff in the `MPI::<func>` classes.

Is there anything I should be aware of?

Comment: there's not likely to be any real bloat. MPI contains plenty of overhead (any cross-process, and especially cross-system API does), and wrapping the API in sensible C++ idioms is not going to make a measurable difference. It is entirely possible that the Boost wrappers are *literally* zero-overhead, for such is the magic of inlining. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should wrap all your includes for C-headers in an `extern "C"` block in order to avoid problems with the name mangling of C++ compilers.

```
extern "C" {
    // include C-headers
}
```

Read more [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html).

Comment: Up-voted this because I totally forgot about C++ FAQ. Nice info there. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not really, as most libraries are prepared to be included in a C++ compiler (if not, you can do as Space Cowboy above suggests). However, I would advice you (if you don't mind) on reconsidering boost MPI. It doesn't add unnecessary bloat, and gives you a more comprehensive interface to MPI in an object-oriented environment. It adds more semantics to types being transferred via MPI, and even gives you more "functional" operators, such as using functors for the calculation operations (e.g. `reduce`), etc. The ammount of code they add is negligible, and most of the time, there is no run-time overhead, as abstractions are implemented via template metaprogramming.

Comment: I also considered templates, but I'm not really convinced how this would play with MPI datatypes. Additionally templates makes my head hurt because of the cryptoerrors as I call them.

Comment: I see... In the case of boost.MPI, the templates are given for you to use, so not so different to use than, say, a `vector<int>`...