# Can MSVC with link-time codegen optimize across C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

If [link-time code generation (LTCG)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/ltcg-link-time-code-generation) is being used with MSVC, is it possible that code can be optimized across the C and C++ language boundary?

For example, can a C function be inlined into a C++ caller?

Comment: Motivated by https://stackoverflow.com/a/48030595/841108

Comment: I'm not comfortable with 4 very closely related questions being asked in a matter of minutes.  (The complete set, including this, are: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48030795/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48030786/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48030706/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48030818/).  I can't help but feel that a single question about which of the 4 compilers can do it would be better.  It feels like a 'rep grubbing' ploy.  Maybe that's harsh, but…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I just tried it with:

```
int foo() { return 5; }
```

in a .c file and:

```
extern "C" int foo();
printf("%d\r\n", foo());
```

in a .cpp the disassembly is:

```
00007FF60F6F3935  mov         edx,5  
00007FF60F6F393A  lea         rcx,[string "%d" (07FF60F727FB4h)]  
00007FF60F6F3941  call        printf (07FF60F701E00h)
```