# Can LTO for clang optimize across C and C++ methods

Tags: c++, c, clang, clang++

If link-time optimization (LTO) is being used with [clang](https://llvm.org/docs/LinkTimeOptimization.html), is it possible that code can be optimized across the C and C++ language boundary?

For example, can a C function be inlined into a C++ caller, or vice-versa?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, yes since Clang produces LLVM intermediate representation, and LTO happens on that LLVM bytecode.

BTW any kind of [link-time-optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization) happens on some *intermediate* representation (of the compiled code), not just on [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) with [relocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)), as kept in every [object file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file). LTO, whatever representation is used (GIMPLE in GCC, LLVM in Clang) is adding and using such extra information (and that is why the object files become fatter).