# C++ to C Conversion issues

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to copy the contents of a C++ (.cpp file) to a C (.c file) code because i need to convert it. Most of the errors I got are now fixed, but there is one remaining.

Here is the code — I have removed all the things that don't relate with the issue:

```
/*Prototype*/
void breakTime(time_t time, tmElements_t tm);
/*Creation*/
static tmElements_t tm;
/*Functions*/
void breakTime(time_t timeInput,tmElements_t &tm){
    tm.Second = 10;
}
```

The compiler gives me:

```
expected ';' , ',' or ')'  before '&' token
```

I tried editing the function and replace `&tm` by just `tm`. It does compile, but the problem is the values that are assigned inside the function to `tm`. Members are not transfered to the outside of the function (which would be the idea).

Any advice how to solve this issues?

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: GCC (its for microprocessors)

Comment: Have you tried to find what `tmElements_t &tm` stands for? You could then be able to figure out similar C concept to make it work. Hint: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference

Comment: @user2921077.: But then in `C` how is that `&` coming at that place? Isn't it? `C` doesn't have any reference like `C++`!

Comment: C doesn’t have references; C++ does. You’ll have to convert the reference to a pointer, and then change calls to the function too. And use appropriate pointer notation in the function of course.

Comment: @coderredoc as i said, i convertet from c++ to c, i was not sure what consequences it would bring. Its a library which i uses for many years, but now that i need it in C, i wanted to keep it and convert ist. It now works with the answer below..

Comment: BTW, you'll better instead keep the C++ code, and call it from C code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch  this does not work, since the compiler cannot compile C and C++ in the same project, you only can have full c++ or full c. Which results in the same - you have to edit libraries, and i choose the way of the lesser work (converting only 10 libraries, instead of like 50)

Comment: @user2921077: No, you can compile a C++ translation unit and another C translation unit and link them together. You'll use `extern "C"` in your C++ code to declare your C functions.This is very common (and most C++ standard library implementations are built that way).  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48030464/841108) for more

Comment: @user2921077: actually, on my Linux desktop, *every* C++ implementation is built above the `libc.so` standard library, and you can call C code from C++ code. Of course, the compiler processes translation units individually (compiled into [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file)) and the linker is "mixing" them. Many C++ libraries (e.g. those from [Qt](http://qt.io/), etc....) are using C libraries (e.g. `libX11`) so calling C code from C++ is *extremely common*.

Comment: @user2921077:  ... and calling C++ code from C code (or libraries) is also possible (but requires some care). For example, [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) is a library, mostly coded in C++ internally, which provides a C API and can be used from programs coded in C. You might find other examples (even if they are not so common). The point is that C and C++ [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)s are similar, and with care, can be used together. However, C++ exceptions make that a bit complicated (so some care is needed).

Comment: @user2921077:  ... so on most implementations (and all the ones I know about) **you can use C and C++ in the same project** (with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), you'll better link with `g++` in such case), at least with enough care (need to understand ABI differences).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes it might be possible, but alot of people have the same problem and have not found a solution yet, the main problem is another i think. Your idea might be true for computer systems, but microprocessors don't run on C or C++, they use their very own instruction set, because of that, at some point all the c/c++ stuff has to be translated to the instruction set of that controller. I think its that point where C and C++ causes a problem when used together. The file that comes out of compile is either *.elf or *.bin and then downloaded to the processor.

Comment: No, this is a confusion. As I said, you need to care about ABI, and indeed the ABI of C++ is quite complex (in the details). This is why coding a kernel in C++ is difficult, but not impossible. See [OSDEV C++](http://wiki.osdev.org/C%2B%2B)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `&` symbol is used here to déclare `tm` as a reference, but C doesn’t have references. You have to remove references for pointers:

```
void breakTime(time_t timeInput, tm_Elements_t* tm) {
    tm->Second = 10;
}
```

Your calls to `breakTime` must also be converted. You should have code like this:

```
time_t timeInput;
tm_Elements_t tm;
breakTime(timeInput, tm);
```

Which must become:

```
time_t timeInput;
tm_Elements_t tm;
breakTime(timeInput, &tm);
```

Note the use of `&` here has a different meaning: it is used to take the address of `tm` which will be passed as a pointer to `breakTime`.

Comment: This works! :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace by a pointer:

```
void breakTime(time_t timeInput, tmElements_t *tm) {
  tm->Second = 10;
}
```

Comment: And fix all the calls.